Is it possible to remote debug a Windows XP application from VS2022?
I have managed zu compile a C++ Project in VS2022 Pro for running on WindowsXP 32bit.
The VS2022 runs on Windows 11.
I used platformtoolset v141_xp and Windows SDK 7.0, since its the last version supporting XP and it's installable by VS2022.
My problem is, that the application crashes on one special XP-Host (the one where it needs to run in production) and the remoteDebugMonitor from VS2022 does not start on Windows XP. ("msvsmon is not a valid win32 app", and I of course used the x86 version).
My application normally dumps a minidump, and it tries to do so, but also my minidump-module seems to crash, so there is no dump written.
Is there another way, to debug a XP-application remote from Win11. Or could it help to install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 on the target XP system?
Thank you.

One way to debug not remote is, to use WinDbg from DebuggingTools for Windows from the Windows SDK 7. Its about 1/2 GByte, but it doesn't need to pay for. In my case it lead me to the Bug since I have access to the GUI of the debuggee and there was enough space on the HDD.

According to
Configuring Programs for Windows XP | Microsoft Learn
Remote debugging on Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 isn't supported by Remote Tools for Visual Studio. To debug an app locally or remotely on Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, use a debugger from an older version of Visual Studio.

Ok thank you, seem to be the only way, to do it remote. I think VS2017 should do the trick.
